# Is there any other expression for 'I’m here on business'?

Tags: phrase-request, conversation

When you go to foreign country and was asked by someone 'what brought you here?',

Is there any other form of answer which has same meaning with 'I’m here on business'?

Comment: Can you please try to include more context. For example: you are where for what business? To sell something or to meet up with a seller to buy something?

Comment: I'm not sure we needed the additional context. The question appears clear enough: Assume the typical situation: You are visiting somewhere and meet a new person. It's very common to be asked, "Are you here on business or pleasure?" etc. And "I"m here on business" is a ritual response. Is there another phrase that expresses the same thing, at the same level of generality/specificity?

Comment: @Kwon We might be able to give you a more useful answer if you explain why you have this question. If you don't wish to say, that is ok! I think the question is clear enough as it is.

Comment: @JimReynolds I am on a business trip. I came here to meet a buyer. I came here to meet a seller. I came here to buy something. I came here to sell something. I came here to sign a contract. I came here to review a contract. I came here to meet up with a lawyer. I came here to research the market. I came here to survey consumers... The question seems to be off-topic as **too broad** or **primarily-opinion-based**.

Comment: @Rath A context is supplied. You want a more specific one. I appreciate that you want this for positive reasons. But we have language to describe general situations, and there's no reason to assume that the OP wants language to describe a more particular situation. *I'm here for work.* Answered. Sometimes an ELL simply wants to know if there's an alternative phrase for something that they are familiar with, and that's it.

Comment: @JimReynolds I see. I just voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go to a foreign country and are asked the question, one of the most broadly used replies is

> I am on a business trip.

A *business trip* is the opposite of a *vacation* or *personal trip* for which you have to spend your own money while a *business trip* is paid for by your company.

There could be more expressions depending on purposes of your business trip, but you don't need to specify your purpose unless it is specifically asked by another party.

Answer (score 2):

We can alternatively say things like:

> I'm here for work.
>
> My company sent me.
>
> My boss sent me.

If you want to show extra friendliness or encourage further conversation with someone, you might say things like:

> I'm here for work this time, but I would like to come back someday for a vacation and get to know some of the friendly people here.

or

> I'm here to work, but I will have some free time this weekend. Do you have any suggestions for places I should visit?

Comment: "'I'm here for work" is about as American as it gets. +1.

Comment: "I'm here on business" is short and sweet and totally acceptable in my country.

You can also give better meaning as @Jim said e.g.
"I'm here to make seek new agencies"
"I'm here on a business contract"
"I'm here to attend a trade show as a buyer"